# Firebase JSON import error Unexpected token ":"

Tags: node.js, json, firebase, parsing, import

Doing a test import into firebase (not a full time developer here) and very new to Firebase and node.js I'm importing the following file and I'm getting the error below after it.

```js
{
    "__collections__": {
        "scores": {
            "comment": "test comment",
            "companyId": "ec24fmJeLA93l5jWPAN0",
            "date": 1607770800.00,
            "email": "bdavis@wftst.com",
            "score": 3,
            "tags": [
                "Supervisor Issues",
                "Communication Issues"
            ],
        "userId": "a8waViyRAJWGr2h6Gc3u",
        "__collections__": {}
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error on my terminal after I run the import.

```
*JSONError: Unexpected token ":" (0x3A) in JSON at position 30 while parsing near "...ctions__\": \n\"scores\": {\n    \"comment\": \"..." in TEST_BDAVIS.json 
  1 | {
  2 | "__collections__": 
> 3 | "scores": {
    |         ^
  4 |     "comment": "test comment",
  5 |     "companyId": "ec24fmJeLA93l5jWPAN0",
  6 |     "date": 1607770800.00,
JSONError: Unexpected token ":" (0x3A) in JSON at position 30 while parsing near "...ctions__\": \n\"scores\": {\n    \"comment\": \"..." in TEST_BDAVIS.json 
  1 | {
  2 | "__collections__": 
> 3 | "scores": {
    |         ^
  4 |     "comment": "test comment",
  5 |     "companyId": "ec24fmJeLA93l5jWPAN0",
  6 |     "date": 1607770800.00,
    at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-firestore-import-export/node_modules/parse-json/index.js:29:21)
    at parse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-firestore-import-export/node_modules/load-json-file/index.js:15:9)
    at Object.module.exports [as default] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-firestore-import-export/node_modules/load-json-file/index.js:18:47)*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the JSON you provided, it seems that a `}` is missing. Where should your entire file end, as well as your first `__collections__` and `scores` section? That may be the cause of the error.